# Fields within request payload are showing up as null in spring boot resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following class, which I am using as a request payload :

```
public class SampleRequest {

    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;

    // Getters and setters removed for brevity.
}
```

I am trying to use it with this resource below (just trying to print it to screen to see things happen) :

```
@PostMapping("/getBySignatureOne")
public ResponseEntity<?> getRequestInfo(@Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) {
    System.out.println(sampleRequest.getToDate());
    System.out.println(sampleRequest.getFromDate());
}
```

This is the JSON request I send up :

```
{
    "fromDate":"2019-03-09",
    "toDate":"2019-03-10"
}
```

The output for the `println`'s are :

```
null
null
```

Do I need to do something to wire this up?

Comment: For request like this it should work: `curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"fromDate":"2019-03-09","toDate":"2019-03-10"}' http://localhost:8080/getBySignatureOne`. How do you test it?

Comment: It seems like `System.out.println(signatureOneRequest.getToDate)` shouldn't compile. Typo or actual code?

Comment: @MichałZiober - I am testing in postman, but with those exact settings...

Comment: @TheHeadRush - oops, typo when copying my code here and trying to make it more anonymous :P

Comment: Your request is valid. You must make a typo in field name, for example `FromDate` or `fromDate1` or something like that. Do you use any annotation to generate getters and setters? It would be great if you show real `POJO` and `JSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find with below configuration the same code is working

Spring-Boot version  : 2.1.3

**Controller**

```
package com.firsttest.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.firsttest.pojo.SampleRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class FirstTestController {



    @PostMapping("/getBySignatureOne")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTestString(@Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) {
        System.out.println("getFromDate : " + sampleRequest.getFromDate());
        System.out.println("getToDate : " + sampleRequest.getToDate());
        return null;//I dont want to send any response.
    }
}
```

**SampleRequest.java**

```
package com.firsttest.pojo;

public class SampleRequest {

    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;

    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }
    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
    public String getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }
    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

}
```

**REQUEST**

```
http://localhost:8080/first/test/getBySignatureOne
httpmethod: POST
Content-Type:application/json
{
    "fromDate":"2019-03-09",
    "toDate":"2019-03-10"
}
```

**OUTPUT Is**

```
getFromDate : 2019-03-09
getToDate : 2019-03-10
```